# Can I see a schematic for a 110 <-> 220 V power converter?

Tags: transformer, ac, autotransformer

I would like to see a schematic for those 110 <-> 220 V power conversion transformers-in-a-box. I've read they are autotransformers (one winding with multiple taps). I'm using one to step up 110 to 220 V and would like to see if there's any way to get split-phase 220 V out of it.

I've looked at industrial isolation transformers with this capability and they are VERY expensive.

**Clarification to re-open**: Can a 110 V to 220 V auto transformer be used to get a 220 V split-phase output? Must an isolation transformer be used? Please give reasons.

Comment: You could take one apart and see how it works. (Be careful of capacitors that may retain a charge)

Comment: Thanks, but no capacitors: just a big honking toroidal transformer/autoformer (mine is rated for 5 KW).

Comment: well there's your answer: your one is a big honking transformer. Some very cheap ones try to fake it, poorly, with a triac. Like a light dimmer set to 50%.

Comment: how is the `VERY expensive` relevant to the question?

Comment: How much schematic do you expect for a transformer?  There's one component - a transformer.  An auto-transformer doesn't even have separate primary and secondary windings.

Comment: Please see my clarified and resubmitted question.

Comment: An 1:1 autotransformer for mains voltage can be run three ways: to half (&halve) voltage to neutral, to double it, and to invert voltage. Only in the last case the centre tap would be connected to neutral, one end to live/phase/hot, the other is the other terminal of the phase "split" at, if not by, neutral.

Comment: I think your question will be closed no matter what. Right now it is not a question but a request, "can you display a schematic for me". You could turn it into a question. "Can I use my transformer model number xxxxxxx to step up from 120 to 240 split-phase?" But then someone will vote to close saying it is about the USE of electronics rather than DESIGN of electronics. This site is very picky about all this stuff.

Comment: It sounds like you have a step-up transformer with a 120 V primary and a 240 V secondary. If the secondary has a center tap you can easily generate split phase power. If not it is basically impossible.

Answer (score 3):

**All the circuits below need input and output fusing. This is not shown, but absolutely necessary for fire safety.**

A 110->220V autotransformer of course provides a split phase output, but the output is not always ground-referenced, and thus you can't use it unless you're careful. In a split-phase supply, the center tap is neutral and bonded to ground. You can get that in an auto-transformer, as long as the central tap is connected to Neutral.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMwZ9D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the schematic above, disregard the dummy primary winding of the transformer - CircuitLab doesn't have an auto-transformer symbol.

As long as the central tap is connected to neutral, LIVE2 is 180 degrees out of phase with LIVE, and thus you have a split-phase supply:

[image: LIVE and LIVE2 waveforms]

> I've looked at industrial isolation transformers with this capability and they are VERY expensive.

Not really. For a fully isolated split-phase supply, you need is two standard 120V-120V isolation transformers, connected as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPF6gx.png)</sup>

If all you want is to *add* a split phase to an existing supply, just one 1:1 isolation transformer does it. It has the same amount of wire as an autotransformer, and should cost about the same.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEKszg.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> Can a 110 V to 220 V auto transformer be used to get a 220 V split-phase output? Must an isolation transformer be used? Please give reasons.

Yes. As long as you don't need isolation, you can use a 110 to 220 VAC autotransformer to generate split phase power from a single phase 110 VAC source.

There are details about grounding and bonding and so forth that you need to take care of.